# Show/hide password with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JS world, and for my practice am trying to build a simple input field where users can toggle (show/hide) their password.

So far I add everything (icons and css) but I don't know why I have this error in my JS code, just run the code and you will see.
Also, my icons are messed up somehow, I don't know how to fix this.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      box-sizing: border-box
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #f9fbff
    }
    
    .source-image {
      width: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: auto;
      position: fixed;
      max-width: 100%;
      display: block
    }
    
    #login-form {
      width: 460px;
      background: 0 0;
      padding: 80px 40px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 40%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      margin: 20px 0
    }
    
    .input_img {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 13px;
      height: 30px
    }
    
    #login-form h1 {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 60px;
      color: #191c3c;
      font-size: 30px
    }
    
    .logoHolder>img {
      width: 60%;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block
    }
    
    #login-form p {
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #333
    }
    
    #login-form p a {
      color: #191c3c;
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    #login-form p {
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #333
    }
    
    #login-form .entryText {
      font-size: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #login-form p a:focus {
      border: 1px solid #515772
    }
    
    #login-form label {
      color: #4a4d67;
      font-weight: 700;
      margin-bottom: 10px !important
    }
    
    .input-box {
      position: relative;
      margin: 30px 0
    }
    
    .input-box input {
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #333;
      border: 1px solid #51577245;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 1.2;
      font-size: 18px;
      outline: 0;
      background: #fff;
      padding: 0 5px;
      height: 72px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding-left: 57px;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 11px 0 rgba(81, 87, 114, .2);
      margin-top: 15px
    }
    
    .input-box input:focus {
      border: 1px solid #515772
    }
    
    .input-box span::before {
      content: attr(data-placeholder);
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 5px;
      color: #515772;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      z-index: -1;
      transition: .5s;
      padding-left: 20px
    }
    
    .validation {
      border-color: #c00000 !important;
      margin-bottom: 7px;
    }
    
    .feedback {
      color: #c00000;
    }
    
    .error {
      color: #c00000;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 30px 0;
    }
    
     ::placeholder {
      margin-left: 60px;
      color: #8b8d9d;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .cursor {
      width: 17px
    }
    
    .input-box span::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      height: 2px;
      background: linear-gradient(120deg, #2196F3, #FF5722);
      transition: .5s
    }
    
    .focus+span::before {
      top: -5px
    }
    
    .focus+span::after {
      width: 100%
    }
    
    .login-btn {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 62px;
      border: none;
      background: #515772;
      background-size: 200%;
      color: #fff;
      outline: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 20px 0 0;
      border-radius: 8px;
      transition: .5s;
      font-size: 18px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      font-weight: 700
    }
    
    .login-btn:focus {
      border: 2px solid #000
    }
    
    .login-btn:hover {
      background-color: #2d3142
    }
    
    .bottom-links {
      margin-top: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 13px
    }
    
    .versionText {
      background: transparent;
      position: fixed;
      inline-size: -webkit-fill-available;
      bottom: 10px;
      z-index: 10;
      text-align: right;
      font-size: 13px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    
    .bottom-links>p>a {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    .bottom-links>p {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:768px) {
      #login-form {
        top: 45%;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .source-image {
        display: none
      }
      .versionText {
        right: 0% !important;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width:576px) {
      #login-form {
        width: 90%;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .source-image {
        display: none
      }
      .versionText {
        right: 0% !important;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width:320px) {
      #login-form {
        width: 90%;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .source-image {
        display: none
      }
      .versionText {
        right: 0% !important;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width:1440px) and (min-width:1024px) {
      #login-form {
        top: 45%;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .versionText {
        right: 0% !important;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
    
    ​ @media (max-width:1440px) {
      .source-image {
        display: none
      }
    }
    
    .version {
      font-size: 13px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .field-icon {
      float: right;
      margin-left: -25px;
      margin-top: -25px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    #password {
      background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/visible.png");
      background-position: 97% center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    #password.visible {
      background-image: url("https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/20/000000/invisible.png");
    }
    
    #toggle-password {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #toggle-password+label {
      text-indent: -9999px;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin-left: -32px;
      cursor: pointer !important;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    const password = document.getElementById("password");
    const togglePassword = document.getElementById("toggle-password");

    togglePassword.addEventListener("click", toggleClicked);

    function toggleClicked() {
      password.classList.toggle("visible");
      if (this.checked) {
        password.type = "text";
      } else {
        password.type = "password";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="sf();">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main>
      <form id="login-form" method="post" name="f">

        <div class="input-box">
          <label for="password">Pass </label>
          <input id="password" name="password" type="password" tabindex="2">
          <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
            class="input_img" alt="">

          <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-password" />
          <label for="toggle-password">Show Password</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="login-btn" tabindex="3" name="Submit">Login</button>

      </form>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Place your script at the end of your HTML file, before the closing `</body>` tag. Your HTML is parsed from top to bottom. So when it reaches your JavaScript, the form does not yet exist and thus selecting elements from it will result in `null` values. `null` is generally an indicator of *not found* or *not existing* when selecting elements.

Comment: you are calling a method that you have not yet created:
`<body onload="sf();">`

Comment: @EmielZuurbier, great, error are gone but  I can not click on icon and show the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute a sf function that is undefined. I dont see this function in your code. You try to find toggle-password before it is rendered on page.
Remove onload from body and add your scripts on end of your body tag.

For quick fix for toggle label add this to your style #toggle-password + label, but i think the idea with using this label is bad:

```
#toggle-password + label {
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

You should also improve padlock styline use this:

```
.input_img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 13px;
    height: 30px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I change bottom from to top 50% and add the translate transfrom to the calc position from the center of the icon